# Not able to track events on GA User ID view if debug mode is disabled

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Analytics, I have created new user ID view and was able to track click events of each user when tag manager's (preview mode/ debug mode) enable and also able to see dynamic value I have passed from data layer as Event Label. But when checking same without debug mode doesn't show my click events on GA.

Using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to implement GA. Have added user view ID in GA and got list of my active unique user ID's as client IDand the code is already tracking page views.

Have passed data using data layer from my code and created data layer variable within Tag Manager to show it to GA.

```
var dataObject = { 
        'user_id': '{{user.id}}',
            'event': eventname,
        'category': catname,
        'label': my_dynamic_value
      };
if(typeof dataLayer != 'undefined'){
dataLayer.push(dataObject);
}
```

If debug mode is disabled, the click event does not get tracked. Not getting actual cause of issue may be need to sent extra parameter or missed to set other GA functions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I feeled funny on myself. Just forgot to publish my changes within tag manager.